# Unknown name value [] for enum class having multiple enums

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums, spring-data-jpa

Dao Class:

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "test" )
public class Test {


@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn( name = "college_id", referencedColumnName = "id" )
private College college;  

@Enumerated( EnumType.STRING )
@Column( name = "gender", length = 500 )
private Gender gender;

@Enumerated( EnumType.STRING )
@Column( name = "section", length = 500 )
private Section section;
...
} 

public enum Gender {
  Male, Female;
}
public enum Section {
  A(0), B(1), C(2);
}
```

RepositoryClass:

```
List<Test> findByGender( Gender gender );
List<Test> findBySection( Section section );
```

If I am calling findBySection(Section.A), it's working as expected.
But If I call findByGender(Gender.MALE), it's throwing error:

`InvalidDataAccessAPIUsageException: Unknown name value [] for enum class [com. .. .constants.Section]`

Strange part is If I am calling, findByCollegeAndGenderNot(College clg, Gender gender) its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have null values in the column section in the database.

A data base column that you want to map to a Java Enum may not be nullable.

So you should check this and add a default value.

Additionally you should alter your column annotations to:

```
@Enumerated( EnumType.STRING )
@Column( name = "gender", length = 500, nullable = false )
private Gender gender;

@Enumerated( EnumType.STRING )
@Column( name = "section", length = 500, nullable = false )
private Section section;
```

Comment: Thanks much, yes there were a few nullable fields in both the columns